# What are the Yuuzhan Vong's perception of Gungans?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, yuuzhan-vong

According to Wookieepedia's description of the Gungans:

> Their technology was peculiar in that everything, from tools to structures is not constructed, but "grown", each device being therefore organically unique.

The Gungans' native technology, therefore, seems to be completely well-aligned and friendly to the Yuuzhan Vong's pro-organic, anti-inorganic culture. Do we know anything about the Yuuzhan Vong's actual perception of Gungans and their technological culture?

Comment: The Yuuzhan Vong and the Gungans... the 2 worst things to ever happen to Star Wars. :(

Comment: @RedCaio did you not like the vong?

Comment: I thought the two worst things were Jar Jar and Binks.

Comment: @CearonO'Flynn I just felt the whole ideas of aliens from outside the galaxy who hate inorganic technology and were immune to the Force was not only silly and uninteresting, but didn't even feel like it belonged in Star Wars at all.

Comment: I'm guessing they like Gungans in general and hate Jar Jar Binks. Just like everyone else does.

Answer (score 6):

Although there are no in-canon references to the Gungans encountering the Yuuzhan Vong, the reality is that they would have probably been **just as appalled by them as they were with the other machinery-obsessed races they found within the Galaxy far far away.** Not only do the Gungans regularly trade plasma with the outside world (used to power machines and droids) but they also marry their organic technology with equipment and machinery they've purchased from offworld traders.

> *The Gungans produce many of their structures using a secret method
>   that actually "grows" the basic skeletons or shells of buildings or
>   vehicles. This gives Gungan constructions a distinctive organic look,
>   which is then complemented by artistic detail, even on simple vehicles
>   like the sub. **Gungan organically generated shells can be combined to
>   make complex constructions, and then modified and fitted with
>   electronic and mechanical components to give them the needed
>   functionality.** The organic skeletons are exceptionally strong, though
>   still susceptible to damage by some of the larger sea monsters
>   encountered in deep waters.*

[image: cut-away view of a Gungan Sub]

Comment: And of course there's Jar Jar */shudder*. I can think of no better reason for planetary genocide then the fact that there's a slim chance of getting him.

Comment: Jar Jar is the Gungan antichrist

Comment: @thegreatjedi - Actually they seem to quite like him (at least by the end of the film), hence why they deserve to be destroyed as a weapon test for the Death Star.